# Compare wstring inline with small differences

Tags: c++

I have a wstring (or wchar_t, whichever fits better), I want to compare it to 6 possible strings (which half of it is dynamic, not constant) with single `IF` statement (if possible). I want to know what's best approach for doing it, instead of several lines and lots of building strings and variables. I want to know professional/shortest/fastest/best way.

In nutshell, I want to do this:
If `MyStr` was equal to :

```
MyCurrentFolder() + "test" OR
MyCurrentFolder() + "test," OR
MyCurrentFolder() + "test, " OR
"test" OR
"test, " OR
"test,"
```

do something...

Please advice.

Comment: Is `MyCurrentFolder()` guaranteed to contain at leas one character not in those suffixes? Like `/` or ``\``?

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes, guaranteed

Comment: "shortest/fastest", pick one, as they are likely to be mutually exclusive.

Comment: Fastest would be: Check for prefix-match, then check for full-match on the rest (without prefix if matched). Do not copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It think something like this would work:

```
bool any_of(std::string const& name, std::initializer_list<std::string> const& list) {
    return list.end() != std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), name);
}
// ...

if (any_of(MyStr, { MyCurrentFolder() + "test",
                    MyCurrentFolder() + "test,",
                    MyCurrentFolder() + "test, ",
                    std::string("test"),
                    std::string("test,"),
                    std::string("test, ") })) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Even knowing who you are, I question your use of `std::string` as a `UnaryPredicate`...

Comment: A touch of metamagic eliminates needless copying of strings to the heap: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b4daf1c6e3335cd, though there's a lot to be said for sticking to `std`.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I haven't really used `std::any_of()` and it seems I'd be better off using `std::find()`. I shall fix the example...

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using `std::set`, assuming `MyCurrentFolder` returns a `std::string`. E.g.:

```
auto tests = std::set<std::string>{
    MyCurrentFolder() + "test",
    MyCurrentFolder() + "test,",
    MyCurrentFolder() + "test, ",
    "test",
    "test, ",
    "test,"};
if (tests.find(MyStr) != tests.end()) {
    // matches
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `std::vector<std::string>` in combination with `std::find()`: it is likely _a lot_ faster than using `std::set<std::string>` (primarily because it needs fewer allocations and has a much smaller memory footprint).

Answer (score 0):

The following meets the requirement of fitting everything in an if-condition:

```
if ([&](wstring s) {vector<wstring>e{ MyCurrentFolder() + L"test", MyCurrentFolder()
       + L"test,", MyCurrentFolder() + L"test, ", L"test", L"test, ",
       L"test," }; return find(e.begin(), e.end(), s) != e.end(); }(MyStr)) {
    ...//YES the string is there;
}
```